# JMeter - Facing Issue while Reading CSV file in While Loop Controller

Tags: jmeter, beanshell, jmeter-3.2

I have single csv file which was attached to 2 samplers one inside loop and one outside. There are 3 rows of data in my input csv, but the SAMPLER inside the loop is ignoring the first row and taking 2nd and 3rd rows. Not sure whats happening...

"While loop" condition has been attached in the image. If any changes in While loop function?
[image: TestPlan]

[image: WhileLoop]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config), First line is ignored if variable names is empty. You should put relevant variable names in first row or fill Variable Names in `CSV Data Set Config` component.

> JMeter supports CSV files which have a header line defining the column names. To enable this, leave the "Variable Names" field empty.

Also, according to [JMeter docs](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__javaScript) avoid using javaScript in function, use jexl3 or groovy instead:

> javaScript is not the best scripting language for performances in JMeter. If your plan requires a high number of threads it is advised to use __jexl3 or __groovy functions.